# CSS3 Gradients: How to make a 1px wide line

Tags: html, css

I want to make a CSS3 gradient that consists of a 1px line.

How can I do this?

I have tried the following code, but the gradient that is produced is too thick:

```
background-image: linear-gradient(left , rgb(255,255,255) 50%, rgb(209,209,209) 50%, rgb(255,255,255) 51%);
```

(see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/KRvER/))

How can I make the line smaller, so its only 1px wide? The percentage values seem to control the positioning of the line, but no matter how much I adjust them, I can't get it to 1px wide!

(Essentially, I am using the line to act as a 'faux columns' background [i.e. to visually separate a left and right column. (Although, to keep the jsFiddle simple, I have removed the columns)] I know there are other ways of doing columns, but this method is the best for my situation)

EDIT: Just to clarify, this is for a slightly odd use case, where the width has to be 100% and no psudeo-elements can be used.

Comment: have you tried using a pseudo element, 1px wide absolutely positioned?

Comment: @ScottSimpson: Thanks for the reply. My use case is slightly odd, so the width has to be 100% and I cannot use pseudo elements. The gradient seems to be the best solution, if I only I could get it to be 1px wide!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.style {        
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left , rgb(255,255,255) 50%, rgb(209,209,209) 50%, rgb(255,255,255) 50.5%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left , rgb(255,255,255) 50%, rgb(209,209,209) 50%, rgb(255,255,255) 50.5%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left , rgb(255,255,255) 50%, rgb(209,209,209) 0%, rgb(255,255,255) 50.5%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(left , rgb(255,255,255) 50%, rgb(209,209,209) 50%, rgb(255,255,255) 50.5%);
}
```

You are not dealing with pixels, you are using percentages. So 1% of your width, which must be 200 is 2px. (I think that is why [this](http://jsfiddle.net/nulref/rZck9/) works, maybe I'm wrong.) You can use percentages decimals, so .5% == 1px.

Comment: Your link to JS fiddle is broken

Comment: @Simon I changed my user name since I posted this. Its fixed now.

Answer (score 8):

```
/* Opera Mobile */
background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #d1d1d1 1px, white 1px);
/* Firefox for Android */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #d1d1d1 1px, white 1px);
/* WebKit browsers */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #d1d1d1 1px, white 1px);
/* new syntax: IE10, Firefox, Opera */
background: linear-gradient(90deg, #d1d1d1 1px, white 1px);
background-position: 100% 0;
background-repeat: repeat-y;
background-size: 50%;
```

### [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ff8E2/1/)

[I used `2px` instead of `1px` in the demo as `1px` was not visible. I only tested in Chrome though.]

You should **always put the unprefixed version last**. There is no need for `-ms-linear-gradient`. IE10 now supports the standard syntax with no prefix and IE9 doesn't support gradients at all.

Comment: this is the only answer that worked. the others "dont work"

Answer (score 6):

If you don't care about IE8 (which you probably don't if you're using gradients) you can use calc().

```
background-image: linear-gradient(left, transparent 50%, rgb(255,255,255) 50%, rgb(255,255,255) calc(50% + 1px), transparent calc(50% + 1px));
```

This is will work with any width element, whereas just using percentages will break down on smaller and wider elements.

Answer (score 0):

I had use this earlier, change it according to your need. I mean change colors and angle as you want

```
background-image: liner-gradient(to bottom, white, white 14%,blue 1%,white 15%);
```